# change layout US International apostrophe in gnome

Tags: linux, keyboard, gnome

I use the US International layout keyboard. I'm french and this layout is perfect for me with a qwerty keyboard.

My only problem is the apostrophe keypad. I'm developper and i use this character ' and " very often but i need to push alt for use it.

I've a image of my keyboard layout:

[image]

I just want switch the "option alt" for use ' and " character without push Alt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in this [site](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap).

So i create a custom Xmodmap:

```
xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap
```

And after, i change the Xmodmap line:

```
keycode  48 = dead_acute dead_diaeresis apostrophe quotedbl apostrophe quotedbl
```

by

```
keycode  48 = apostrophe dead_diaeresis dead_acute quotedbl dead_acute quotedbl
```

And it's works!

EDIT: If you want your Xmodmap run each login you need to add this line in your .bashrc

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

If xmodmap doesn't run turned off "keyboard" gnome plugin with this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false
```

[ref1](https://superuser.com/questions/185345/why-wont-my-xmodmap-command-run-on-startup-login)
[ref2](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1194968#p1194968)